# How to compose functions that modify a struct in Rust

Tags: rust, functional-programming, function-composition

Take a super-simple struct Foo:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    a: i32
}
```

and a compose macro I got [here](https://functional.works-hub.com/learn/functional-programming-jargon-in-rust-1b555):

```
macro_rules! compose {
    ( $last:expr ) => { $last };
    ( $head:expr, $($tail:expr), +) => {
        compose_two($head, compose!($($tail),+))
    };
}

fn compose_two<A, B, C, G, F>(f: F, g: G) -> impl Fn(A) -> C
where
    F: Fn(A) -> B,
    G: Fn(B) -> C,
{
    move |x| g(f(x))
}
```

I can define a simple function that takes a mutable reference and modifies the struct and returns the reference it was handed:

```
fn foo(x: &mut Foo) -> &mut Foo {
    x.a = x.a * 2;
    x
}
```

and it works as expected:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = Foo { a: 3 };
    let y = foo(&mut x);
    println!("{:?}", y.a); // prints 6
    y.a = 7;
    println!("{:?}", x); // prints Foo { a: 7 }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to define a second simple function and compose the two:

```
fn bar(x: &mut Foo) -> &mut Foo {
    x.a = x.a + 1;
    x
}

fn main() {
    let baz = compose!(foo, bar);
    let mut x = Foo { a: 3 };
    let y = baz(&mut x);
    println!("{:?}", y.a);
}
```

I get an error that the mutable borrow of x in main `let y = baz(&mut x);` doesn't live long enough. I don't think I understand that compose macro well enough to understand what's gong wrong.

Also when I print the struct bound to `x` in the first version it works because it's after the last use of the mutable borrow `y` so I can immutably borrow `x` to print it. But in the second version if I try to print `x` at the end it says it's still borrowed mutably. Something in the compose macro seems to be "holding on" to that mutable borrow of `x`?

How do I make this work? *Can* this be made to work?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1304dbe8e0b5cc93752b4bb77431aaa)

## Edit based on comments:

It seems that while the closure in `compose_two` doesn't actually hold on to the mutable reference to the struct the return type doesn't specify that it doesn't (closures *close over* captured variables right?), and so the compiler is forced to assume that it might. How do I convince the compiler that I'm not holding that reference?

Comment: [Here's a more minimal example, without the macro or `Foo`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=084664846f15f60c09f262026930ced7).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yeah good point. I should have omitted the macro since all it does is (AFAICT) recurse with the compose_two fn for n arguments.

Comment: The compiler explains what is the difference: "borrow might be used here, when `baz` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `impl Fn(&mut i32) -> &mut i32`". What is not clear?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman so the return type of `compose_two` is a concrete type that implements the Fn trait (i.e. a closure), and that trait has a destructor that gets run when main exits and `baz` goes out of scope, and the closure is still capturing the argument reference. I *think* I follow that far. What I don't understand is why that's a problem in this case, or how to fix it. I mean I get that I can't immutably borrow x while the closure is holding on to the &mut ref, but how do I get it to release it? And why isn't it just freed when main exits?

Comment: The closure _doesn't_ hold a reference to `x`, but it _could_. An opaque type (`impl Trait`) is opaque (well, at least partially), and if we would leak wether the type implements `Drop`, it would not be so opaque anymore. If you're asking how to solve that, I can think of at least four different ways, none is perfect. But please clarify in the OP that this is what you're asking, and not why it happens.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I updated the question. Please let me know if that works for you, or post an answer it passes muster.

Comment: I'm preparing the answer; it's long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Can* this be made to work?

No. But depending on your use-case, maybe yes.

You can make it work if either:

- You can constrain the function types to be `Copy` (if you are using function items (`fn`), they are always `Copy`, but for closures this may be a problem if they capture non-`Copy` types).
- You can use nightly.
- You can change the user of `compose!()` (`main()`).
- You can limit `compose!()` to references (mutable references, to be precise, but you can make a version for shared references too. Of course, if you want to make separate versions for references and owned types, this is fine).

There are three factors here, that joined together they convince the compiler `x` can be used after its lifetime. If we break one of them, it will work. Two of them are actually false, but the compiler doesn't know that (or doesn't want to rely on that). The factors are:

1. The compiler believes that the returned closure can capture its parameter. This is false, as I will explain in a minute, but the compiler does not know that.
2. The compiler believes the closure has a drop implementation, and can use `x` (captured in step 1) inside this drop. In fact, the compiler knows it doesn't, but because we used `impl Trait`, it is forced to treat it as if it implemented drop, so it will not be a breaking change to add one.
3. `x` is dropped before `baz`. This is true (variables are dropped in reversed order to their declaration), and combined with the two previous beliefs of the compiler it means that when `baz` will (potentially) use its captured `x` in its drop, it will be after `x`'s lifetimes.

Let's start with the last claim. It is the easiest to break, because you only need to swap the order of `x` and `baz`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = 3;
    let baz = compose_two(foo, bar);
    let y = baz(&mut x);
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

But it is not always possible to change `main()`, or it may not be possible to declare `x` before `baz`.

So let's return to the second claim. The compiler believes the closure has a `Drop` impl because it is in `impl Trait`. What if it would not be?

Unfortunately, this requires nightly, because writing closures manually requires the features [`fn_traits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/library-features/fn-traits.html) and [`unboxed_closures`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/unboxed-closures.html). But it is definitely possible (and a nice side benefit is that the function can be conditionally `FnOnce`/`FnMut`/`Fn` depending on what its input functions are):

```rust
#![feature(fn_traits, unboxed_closures)]

struct ComposeTwo<G, F>(F, G);

impl<A, B, C, G, F> std::ops::FnOnce<(A,)> for ComposeTwo<G, F>
where
    F: FnOnce(A) -> B,
    G: FnOnce(B) -> C,
{
    type Output = C;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, (x,): (A,)) -> Self::Output {
        (self.1)((self.0)(x))
    }
}

impl<A, B, C, G, F> std::ops::FnMut<(A,)> for ComposeTwo<G, F>
where
    F: FnMut(A) -> B,
    G: FnMut(B) -> C,
{
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, (x,): (A,)) -> Self::Output {
        (self.1)((self.0)(x))
    }
}

impl<A, B, C, G, F> std::ops::Fn<(A,)> for ComposeTwo<G, F>
where
    F: Fn(A) -> B,
    G: Fn(B) -> C,
{
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, (x,): (A,)) -> Self::Output {
        (self.1)((self.0)(x))
    }
}

fn compose_two<G, F>(f: F, g: G) -> ComposeTwo<G, F> {
    ComposeTwo(f, g)
}
```

Another way to break this assumption is by making the returned closure `Copy`. `Copy` type can never implement `Drop`, and the compiler knows that, and assumes they don't. Unfortunately, because the closure captures `f` and `g`, they need to be `Copy` too:

```rust
fn compose_two<A, B, C, G, F>(f: F, g: G) -> impl Fn(A) -> C + Copy
where
    F: Fn(A) -> B + Copy,
    G: Fn(B) -> C + Copy,
{
    move |x| g(f(x))
}
```

The last way is the most complicated to explain. First, I need to explain why the compiler thinks the closure can capture `x`, while in fact it cannot.

Let's first think why the closure cannot do that: what lifetime will it put in place of the `'?` below?

```rust
struct Closure {
    f: some_function_type,
    g: some_function_type,
    captured_x: Option<&'? mut Foo>,
}
```

When `baz` was defined (where we must decide what lifetime we'll use), we still don't know what will be passed to the closure, and so we don't know what lifetime we should use!

This knowledge, which is essentially "the closure can be called with *any* lifetime", is passed through [*Higher-Ranked Trait Bounds (HRTB)*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#higher-ranked-trait-bounds) in Rust, spelled `for<'lifetime>`. So, `A` in `compose_two()` should've been HRTB.

But here lies the problem: generic parameters cannot be HRTB. They must be instantiated with a *concrete* lifetime. So, the compiler chooses some lifetime `'x` for `baz`, and this lifetime must be bigger than `baz` itself - otherwise it would contain a dangling lifetime - and therefore it theoretically could have a member with that lifetime, and so the compiler believes `baz` can store the reference to `x`, while in reality it cannot.

If only we could make it HRTB...

We can! If we does not make it completely generic, and instead specify it as a reference:

```rust
fn compose_two<A, B, C, G, F>(f: F, g: G) -> impl for<'a> Fn(&'a mut A) -> &'a mut C
where
    F: for<'a> Fn(&'a mut A) -> &'a mut B,
    G: for<'a> Fn(&'a mut B) -> &'a mut C,
{
    move |x| g(f(x))
}
```

Or, using elided form, since HRTB is the default for `Fn` trait bounds:

```rust
fn compose_two<A, B, C, G, F>(f: F, g: G) -> impl Fn(&mut A) -> &mut C
where
    F: Fn(&mut A) -> &mut B,
    G: Fn(&mut B) -> &mut C,
{
    move |x| g(f(x))
}
```

It unfortunately also requires `B: 'static`, because the compiler cannot conclude `B` will live long enough (another limitation of the language), but then it works!

```rust
fn compose_two<A, B: 'static, C, G, F>(f: F, g: G) -> impl Fn(&mut A) -> &mut C
where
    F: Fn(&mut A) -> &mut B,
    G: Fn(&mut B) -> &mut C,
{
    move |x| g(f(x))
}
```

Comment: For 3. we don't necessarily need to declare `x` before `baz`, we could also `drop(baz)` ahead of time, and that might be easier/possible to implement even if rearranging `x` and `baz` declarations isn't.

Answer (score 1):

First, it helps to inline the macro a couple of times using the `rust-analyzer` quick fix (keybind `ctrl+.` in vscode):

```
fn main() {
    let baz = compose_two(foo, bar);
    let mut x = Foo { a: 3 };
    let y = baz(&mut x);
    println!("{:?}", y.a);
}
```

In this case it just calls `compose_two` with the given functions. The full compiler diagnostic for the error is:

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:34:17
   |
34 |     let y = baz(&mut x);
   |                 ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
35 |     println!("{:?}", y.a);
36 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `x` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `baz` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `impl Fn(&mut Foo) -> &mut Foo`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined
```

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here but I think the problem is that the compiler can't infer that the mutable reference isn't used after the call to `baz` for some reason. It works if you inline the call to `compose_two`:

```
    let baz = move |x| bar(foo(x));
```

It works if you define `baz` as a separate function:

```
fn baz(x: &mut Foo) -> &mut Foo{
    compose_two(foo, bar)(x)
}

fn main() {
    let bazz = baz;
    let mut x = Foo { a: 3 };
    let y = bazz(&mut x);
    println!("{:?}", y.a);
}
```

But I don't know why it can't infer that from the `impl Fn(&mut Foo) -> &mut Foo` type of `baz` (the variable).

Edit: some discussion in the question's comments has shed some light here. As Chayim Friedman described, the compiler can't assume much from the `impl Fn(&mut Foo) -> &mut Foo` type so it assumes it could be holding the reference (but it isn't). Which is why it works if you inline the closure or extract baz to it's own function, because then the compiler has more information.

In this case, it can be fixed by declaring `x` first so that `baz` (which the compiler thinks is holding a mutable reference to `x`) is dropped before `x`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = Foo { a: 3 };
    let baz = compose_two(foo,bar);
    let y = baz(&mut x);
    println!("{:?}", y.a);
}
```

Comment: I'm giving the nod to Chayim's answer because it goes into greater detail but I appreciate and upvoted yours. Thanks!